bibtex: "extra.label is an unknown function"
I am using a bst file customized by someone else. I get the following error from bibtex:
"extra.label is an unknown function---line 299 of file imac_2021.bst.bst"

Here is the section of the bibtex file causing the error:
FUNCTION {format.date}
  { year empty$
    { "" }
    { year " (" swap$ * extra.label * ")\removeperiod" *}
  if$
  before.all 'output.state :=
  }

I get this error while using texshop but not while using overleaf.
Any help in resolving this error is greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Please add a minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)

I do not see a way of uploading the bst file that causes the bug. Is that possible?

Changing part of ENTRY fixed the problem:

